# How do I generate a diff report for non-coders?

Tags: reporting, diff

I've used many of the diff tools listed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111025085647/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool).   What I haven't found is one that has good reporting tools.   The changes to our software baseline that will be reviewed at a change control board.   I am looking for a diff tool that will produce a report of differences that can be viewed by the review team using a common file format *(pdf/word/html/etc)*.      I'd like a report that looks similar to what I see when I use a visual tool like WinMerge or BeyondCompare.    The standard diff output just seems to confuse my manager.

I'd like to see something like this (without having to generate a screenshot):

[image: diff]

Not this:

```
9c3
< #define A(h,c)h[c&7]+=c,h[3]|=c;
---
> #define A(h,c)h[c&7]+=c,h[3]|=c
19,20c13,14
< if(v=v&v*4&v<<4&v<<6&v<<8){t+=4;a=v&=~(v/4);}
< else if(t)for(i=(h[i]&63)/(i?i:8);i-->5;)v=a&=a-1;
---
> if(v=v&v<<2&v<<4&v<<6&v<<8){t+=4;a=v&=~(v/2);}
> else if(t)for(i=(h[i]&63)/(i?i:8),v=a;i-->5;)a&=a-1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BeyondCompare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/) - the only recommendation I will give to anyone. And it's visual is much intuitive than having angular brackets.

They have one nice feature of Reports - export to HTML the current difference view. Refer at the end of this page: [layout of HTML report](https://web.archive.org/web/20141002102344/http://www.scootersoftware.com:80/tour/tour10.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [scootersoftware.com](http://www.scootersoftware.com/images/TextCompare.png))</sub>

Comment: One time I have seen this tool uses by lawyer (compare two different editions of same agreement). Great tool!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link. This is something that I created for the sole purpose of creating diff between 2 folders and also generate some PMD reports for the delta.

http://diffreport.sourceforge.net/

Comment: it is considered good practice to include actual solution/answer here, instead of ONLY a link.